# How do i reload  same page using window.location in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a JQuery Function

```
(function ($) {
jQuery.fn.saveUser = function(destinationUrl) {
    this.click(function() {
        var formData = 'option=saveuser&'+$('form#save-user').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'process.php',
            data: formData,
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg === 'empty') {
                    alert('Required Values Missing');
                } else if(msg === 'duplicateEmail'){
                    alert('Email already exist');
                } else {
                    window.location = destinationUrl;
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

now based on some actions and events, i redirect it to different pages, in this case i need it to redirect it to two different url.

```
1) reload the same page preserving all $_GET variables via URI

2) reload to the specified url.
```

the below jQuery code can redirect me to any specific url.

```
$('form#save-user button[name="save-user-close"]').saveUser(function() {
    return 'index.php?users';
});
```

however i am not getting how do i make it redirect to the same page for example.

```
$('form#save-user button[name="save-user-close"]').saveUser(function() {
    return location.reload(true);
});
```

i know the above code will not work, i am confused on how do i go with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never calling the function in your code, so it would not work whatever you put in the function. Intead of:

```
window.location = destinationUrl;
```

you should call the function, and let the function do the redirection:

```
destinationUrl();
```

(And you probably want to rename the parameter to reflect the change of usage.)

So your functions should do the redirection instead of returning the URL, so that you can use the `reload` method in the second one:

```
$('form#save-user button[name="save-user-close"]').saveUser(function() {
  window.location = 'index.php?users';
});
```

and:

```
$('form#save-user button[name="save-user-close"]').saveUser(function(e) {
  location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: `return location.reload(true);` does not work for my jQuery function.

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: Yes, I realised that it was a bit more complex. I edited the answer.

Comment: this is nice, i am a novice in jQuery so i have a very little understanding on how this thing works :) thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
window.location.href=window.location.href;
```

or

```
 location.replace(URL);
```

but preserving the variables u can approach querystring or session variables